# Pass data values as parameters Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am a newbie in Vue.js. Not sure how to return a function result to data value.

I have an array of objects. Each has data and a query expression.

I have two functions: First one changes request expression (string) and turns it into valid json then calls second function (where I pass data of an object) Second - sends an API request and in case of valid response writes it into passed data.

I want to use function dynamically (I mean I've got three requests but I want to use single function that only changes the request).

The code:

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        dropList: [
            {
                label: "label_1",
                data: [],
                expresion: "expression_1"
            },
            {
                label: "label_2",
                data: [],
                expresion: "expression_2"
            }
        ],
        chartData: []
    },
    
    methods: {
        getDropListData() {
            
            this.dropList.forEach( value => {
                var config = {
                    expression: value.expresion,
                    applyDimensionRights: true,
                };
                this.getData(JSON.stringify(config), value.data);
            });
        },
        
        datasourceExecute() {

            var config = {
                expression: "expression_3",
                applyDimensionRights: true,
            };
            
            this.getData(JSON.stringify(config), this.chartData);
    
        },
        
        getData(payload, targetDataSetName) {
            var url = "url";
            this.sendRequest(
                url,
                "POST",
                payload,
                function (responseData) {
                  if (responseData.isOK) {

                    targetDataSetName = responseData.data;

                  } else {
                    this.makeToast(responseData.message, "danger");
                    console.log("Error getting data");
                  }
                }.bind(this)
            );  
        },
```

`responseData` is OK. I get a valid response in the console. However data isn't changing.

Comment: You need to add `.bind(this)` to the `getData()` function.

Comment: @AztecCodes Vue comp methods are already bound

Answer (score 0):

I figuered it out:
I passed a reference not a value therefore no changes for initial data were made

Comment: I see an issue with your `dropList` as you're changing an object proprty, so Vue reactivity will not work. A more Vue approach would be to collect all results and apply the new array to `dropList`, of course you have to map the incoming data to fit the `dropList` item structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare data option as a function with a return value, not an
object:

```
new Vue({
  data(){
    return {
      ...
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).